# Windows Phone add phone contacts to a list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I would like to memorize all the phone's contacts to a list that I create that I will work with later, I need a loop that will go from the first to the last contact, which will put the number and name into a list.
Haven't got a clue how to do that loop, don't know where it starts, how to loop trough or where it ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good example how to access the contact list.

[How to access contact data for Windows Phone - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286416%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_AccessingContactData)

Basically you create a new `Contacts` object and subscribe to the `SearchCompleted` Event and then start a search. `SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "State String 1")` searches for all phone contacts.

Code Sample from link:

```
{
    Contacts cons = new Contacts();

    //Identify the method that runs after the asynchronous search completes.
    cons.SearchCompleted += new EventHandler<ContactsSearchEventArgs>(Contacts_SearchCompleted);

    //Start the asynchronous search.
    cons.SearchAsync(String.Empty, FilterKind.None, "Contacts Test #1");
}

void Contacts_SearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
{
    //Do something with the results.
    MessageBox.Show(e.Results.Count().ToString());
}
```